# How to print or echo rows when using COUNT(*) and SUM()

Tags: php, mysql

I generated the below query for php using PHP-MYADMIN, 
My question is how to print the 30 rows it generates?  when i use "see quote" it just errors out.

i am trying to echo the rows with search term and count in < div >< /div > tags each in its own.

1. Facebook 38 searches
2. Another Feed 25 searches
3. Timeline 18 searches

and so on to row 30.

---

> $result=mysql_query($sql)

---

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `search`, SUM(searched) FROM `af_timeline_search` GROUP BY `search` ORDER BY SUM(searched) DESC LIMIT 0, 30 ';
```

---

```
        /* top searches */
        $sqlthis = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `search` FROM `af_timeline_search` GROUP BY `search` ORDER BY `Rows` DESC');
        $num=mysql_num_rows($sqlthis);
        $arrS = mysql_fetch_array($sqlthis); 
        $i=0;
        while ($i < $num){
        echo 'Search '.$arrS[$i].'';
            $i++;
        }
```

---

Screen Shot of Query in PHPmyadmin.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. Can you clarify it?

Comment: sorry mostly, i am a bit new with mysql, i am just trying to loop the query as to show each row.

1. facebook 38 searches
2. AnotherFeed 25 searches
etc. and so on.

Comment: Jared, sorry if i am so new to this but i am not sure how to use the alias.  would it be possible to post the correct loop?

Comment: Wish i knew how to ask for what i need, i guess this is just beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this.  Thank you all for your guidance.  :-)  "you all rock"

---

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows, search, SUM(searched) FROM anotherfeed.af_timeline_search GROUP BY search ORDER BY SUM(searched) DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error! yo.');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($row);
            echo '</pre>';
```

---

```
        /* top searches with loop */
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows, search, SUM(searched) FROM anotherfeed.af_timeline_search GROUP BY search ORDER BY SUM(searched) DESC LIMIT 0, 20";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error! yo.');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo '  (';
         echo urldecode($row['search']) . " " . $row['SUM(searched)'] . "";
         echo ')  ';
          }
```

---

I am able to print the array, hopefully i can get the loop down with a while statement.  Feel free to add a loop if you have or know one that is better...  Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best you can do is to take a look at this: [mysql-fetch-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

There you'll find the answer on how to loop over that array :)

Comment: thank you mostly, i have spent all day trying fetch-array i just can not seem to get it down i suppose.  It always errors out on mysql_query if anything else is added after.  I was told it is because how i am using COUNT() and SUM in same query.  If you can post a sample of the loop i would be forever in your debt.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOURDATABASE");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['search'] . " " . $row['somenumber'];
  echo " searches";
  }

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: I can't read what it says SUMp...something. Either way that would be the second $row value.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in \TimeLinePopular.php on line 454

Comment: $sqlthis = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `search`, SUM(searched) FROM `af_timeline_search` GROUP BY `search` ORDER BY `Rows` DESC');
   $i=0;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlthis))
     {
     echo $row['search'] . " " . $row[''.$i.''];
     echo " searches";
     $i++;
     }

Comment: SUM(searched)  is what i am using to join the total searches for each row that has same id.

Comment: Did you happen to see the button at the top of Phpmyadmin that says create PHP code?  Do the query you want and give that a shot.  I'm sorry is this line 454??  If so delete it and replace with the code I supplied.  I'm hoping I'm understanding what you want.

Comment: and_27_y  the query i posted is from the php generator, it just does not give you the loop code.

Comment: So what is line 454?  You may want to take this to chat to stop a lengthy comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3974/discussion-between-and-27-y-and-shawn-e-carter)